# comparing multiple columns of matrix together

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 50x50 matrix named nghlist(i,j) containing 0 and 1 values. 1 means there is a relation between (i,j).

There is another 5x50 matrix named chlist.

I need to check the nghlist matrix and if there is any connection between i and j (nghlist(i,j)==1) then I need to go to the chlist matrix and compare the values on column i and column j. For example compare columns (1,3,8,21,52) and get how many similar values they share together. i.e. I find all those columns have 3 similar values.

I tried using following code. But the problem is I need to compare the unknown number of columns (depend on the node connection (nghlist) for example 4 or 5 columns) together.

```
for i=1:1:n
for j=1:1:n
    if (i~=j & nghlist(i,j)==1)
        sum(ismember(chlist(:,i),chlist(:,j)));
    end
end
end
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

++++ simplified example ++++++
take a look at the example https://i.stack.imgur.com/X48ZN.jpg

nghlist matrix:

```
1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   1
0   0   1   1   1
0   0   1   1   1
```

chlist matrix:

```
3   1   4   5   4
4   3   5   6   5
5   4   6   7   6
```

In this example since node 1 is connected to nodes 2 and 3, I need to compare column 1,2 and 3 from chlist. The output would be 1 (because they only share value '4').

And this value for node 5 would be 2 (because columns 3,4 and 5 only share value '5' and '6'). I hope now it is clear.

Comment: Two questions: (1) if chlist has more than 5 columns, it'd be 5x50?! (2) How can there be more than two columns (i and j) to be compared if nghlist only yields a connection between these two?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the typos: it is chlist  is 5x50.
Actually I have a network of 50 nodes which I distribute them randomly in the network. If the two node distance is less than a predefined value they are neighbors. So the connection between node 3 and 18 will set to be 1. So imagine a node has 5 neighbors. I want to compare all this 5+1 (5 neighbors + node itself) rows in chlist matrix.

Comment: Provide a simplified worked example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve it this way. I compare the first and second column of tempb and put the result in tem. then compare tem with third column of tempb and so on. Anyway thank you **finmor** and also **pyStarter**, your codes has inspired me. However I knew its not the best way, but at least it works.

```
for i=1:size(nghlist,1)
s(i)=0;
j=2;
row=nghlist(i,:);
idx=find(row==1);
tempb=chlist(:,idx);
if (size(tempb,2)>1)
    tem=intersect(tempb(:,1),tempb(:,2));
    if (size(tempb,2)<=2)
        s(i)=size(tem,1);
    end
    while (size(tempb,2)>j & size(tem)~=0)
        j=j+1;
        tem= intersect(tem(:,1),tempb(:,j));
        s(i)=size(tem,1);
    end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, the indices of the columns that are to be compared is called idxList:

```
idxList = [1,3,8,21,50];
```

You may compare all with the first one and use "AND" to find the minimum number of shared values:

```
shared = ones(size(chlist(:,i)))
for ii = 2:length(idxList)
    shared = (shared == (chlist(:,idxList(1)) == chlist(:,idxList(ii))))
end
```

Finally, sum as before

```
sum(shared)
```

I haven't checked the exact code, but the concept should become clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I played around with your code and tried to make it happen but unfortunately I couldn't manage it. Maybe I couldn't understand the idxList concept here.

Comment: Please check my edited posting. I explicitly added the variable *idxList*.

Answer (score 0):

If the result of your simplified example is [1,2,0,3,2] then the following code worked for me.
 (Matrix *a* stands for *nghlist* and matrix *b* for *chlist*, result is stored in *s* )

```
for i = 1:size(a,1)
   s(i)=0;
   row = a(i,:);
   idx = find(row==1);
   idx = idx(idx~=i);
   tempb = b(:,idx);
   for j=1:size(tempb,1)
      if sum(sum(tempb==tempb(j,1)))==size(tempb,2)
          s(i)=s(i)+1;
      end
   end
end
```

For every node you find all the ones in its row, then discard the one referring to the node itself. Pick the appropriate columns of chlist (line 6) and create a new matrix. For every element of the 1st column of this matrix check if it exists in all other columns.If it does, update the s value

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you misunderstand some part of my question. The final result should be [1,1,0,2,2] since node 1 has only number 4 as common number with all its neighbors. Also node 2 has only number 4 shared with all neighbors. Node 3 has no common number with all neighbors. Nodes 4 and five share 2 numbers (5,6) with all their neighbors.
Anyway, your code has helped me in other ways which I didn't expect. Yet I am working to solve this problem. Maybe now you can help me since I made the question more clear.

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood the comparisons' part...However if you remove the line 'idx=idx(idx~=i)' the result will be the same as yours.